# left-hand operand of comma has no effect?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, warnings

I'm having some trouble with this warning message, it is implemented within a template container class

```
int k = 0, l = 0;
    for ( k =(index+1), l=0; k < sizeC, l < (sizeC-index); k++,l++){
        elements[k] = arryCpy[l];
    }
    delete[] arryCpy;
```

this is the warning i get

```
cont.h: In member function `void Container<T>::insert(T, int)':
cont.h:99: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
cont.h: In member function `void Container<T>::insert(T, int) [with T = double]':
a5testing.cpp:21:   instantiated from here
cont.h:99: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
cont.h: In member function `void Container<T>::insert(T, int) [with T = std::string]':
a5testing.cpp:28:   instantiated from here
cont.h:99: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
>Exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comma expression `a,b,c,d,e` is similar to

```
{
  a;
  b;
  c;
  d;
  return e;
}
```

therefore, `k<sizeC, l<(sizeC - index)` will only return `l < (sizeC - index)`.

To combine conditionals, use `&&` or `||`.

```
k < sizeC && l < (sizeC-index)  // both must satisfy
k < sizeC || l < (sizeC-index)  // either one is fine.
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `k < sizeC, l < (sizeC-index)` only returns the result of the right-hand test. Use `&&` to combine tests:

```
k < sizeC && l < (sizeC-index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
for ( k =(index+1), l=0; k < sizeC && l < (sizeC-index); k++,l++){
```

When you have a comma expression is evaluated the rightmost argument is returned so your:

```
 k < sizeC, l < (sizeC-index)
```

expression evaluates to:

```
 l < (sizeC-index)
```

and thus misses

```
 k < sizeC
```

use the `&&` to combine the conditions instead.